# Basic equations using variables in linux

Tags: bash, unix

I've been stuck on this for a little while now and i think i've been going round in circles for what is probably a very easy answer.

I'm trying to do a simple equation involving variables in a bash script. Below is the basics of my more complex bash script. Could anyone help me with this please?

On top of this i would also like to complete the final equation with the below (1 step at a time). I saw that I would probably be required to use bc to handle the non integer, but i didnt get that far!

```
#!/bin/bash
a=20
b=25
echo $( ("$a" + "$b") )
```

Error

```
bash -x test1
+ a=$'20\r'
+ b=$'25\r'
++ $'20\r' + $'25\r'
test1: line 4: $'20\r': command not found
+ echo $'\r'
```

Final equation (not much different i know)

```
 #!/bin/bash
    a=20
    b=25
    echo $( ("$a" + "$b" / 100) )
```

Comment: `\r` - you use windows line endings. You have to convert the file from windows endings to linux - ie. remove the `\r` character on the end of each line in the file.

Comment: To use `bc` and here documents: `a=1;b=3;bc <<< "scale=4;($a+$b)/100"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something as below

```
echo $((a + b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the script slightly, the following script will give you the desired result, `45`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
a=20
b=25
echo $(($a + $b))
```

Or, alternatively

```sh
#!/bin/bash
a=20
b=25
echo $((a + b))
```